# Eloquent - Adding a query to the main query instance from within a closure

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 8, I am trying to execute an additional where clause on the main query from within a closure, in the event that the relationship doesn't exist for that record (Rather than executing the additional where clause on a non-existent relationship).

Example Table Structure:

```
Tasks:
task_id
task_name
first_review_due

Actions:
action_id
action_performed
next_review_due
task_id
```

Code:

```
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include overdue tasks.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeOverdue($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('Action', function ($query) {
                        $query->latest()->where('next_review_due','<', Carbon::today());
                    })->orWhereDoesntHave('Action', function($query) {
                        $query->where('first_review_due','<',Carbon::today());
                    });
    }
```

The query I am trying to execute should use the "next_review_date" from the latest result in the actions table (If an instance of the relationship exists). If the relationship isn't present, it should run the query with "first_review_date" on the main table. My current code has been included above.

How could this scope be amended in order to query the first_review_due column in the current model **only** in the event that the Action relationship doesn't exist (Rather than looking for first_review_due in the Action table)?

Comment: Please write your question. I can only read your post as "statement" at the moment.

Comment: Apologies. Edited to add a question at the bottom, hopefully that makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier if you create latestAction relation:

```
public function latestAction() {
    return $this->hasOne(Action::class)->latest();
}
```

Then, on the query part, you can directly access latestAction:

```
$query
    ->whereHas('latestAction', function($latestAction) {
        return $latestAction->where('next_review_due','<', Carbon::today());
    })
    ->orWhere(function($q) {
        return $q->doesntHave('latestAction')
                 ->where('first_review_due','<',Carbon::today());
    });
```